# Is there a Python library to run Bash commands in a non-Linux OS

Tags: windows, python, bash

Is there a Python library to run Bash commands in a non-Linux OS? I want to run Bash commands in Windows using Python. Is there a Python library for that? Please help.

PS- should have an easy syntax. I don't want stuff with auth keys, etc.

Comment: which bash commands would you like to run in particular, and do they have to be Python functions? Many bash programs have versions compiled for Windows and can be called from Python as subprocesses.

Comment: actually i want some thing like this - `run_bash("echo 'hey' | lolcat")`. and almost all of the commands must work. note that it'll be a bonus if i can run `sudo` and `apt-get`

Comment: Your questions asked here are very vague and mostly unrealistic. This one is caused by lack of knowledge it seems - I don't think you understand what "bash commands" are and why this Python library question doesn't make much sense. You can run any sort of CLI command in Python and your question should be how you should get them in your system. But then you need to be specific about which commands and which system. If Windows, then you have e.g. Cygwin. But if you are talking about stuff such as `lolcat` then that's a random 3rd party exec. And `apt-get` has no purpose on incompatible systems

Comment: `apt-get` WIndows alternatives would be `choco` or `winget` that target correct repositories with types of installers or executables that work in Windows

Comment: okay. so what about the others??

Comment: i actually understand what bash is. it is a shell that is used in unix and linux systems. I simply want to use it in windows through python. thats all :)

Comment: @lunix - Please edit your question to provide the extra information, rather than using comments.

Comment: Using a type of a shell is very different to running commands available within the system through that shell. I still have no idea what you're trying to achieve exactly. But your partial answer is probably either a) mentioned Cygwin or b) aliases. Or maybe c) and running your Python code in Docker on Windows so that you can utilize classic Unix/Linux commands